# InputMismatchException for unknown reasons

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have this assignment and I have written a code that I think is logically correct. However when I compile it and feed in test cases, it gives me `InputMismatchException` and it seems to appear on the line of the first `"SIT"`, where the errors came from the `int` that comes after.I can't reproduce the error on a simpler program. Can someone suggest what could be wrong here? Do inform me if more information is required. Thanks.

**Source code**

```
import java.util.*;

class Grids {
    private void run() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = sc.nextInt();
        int numRow = sc.nextInt();
        int numCol = sc.nextInt();
        int [][] rowByCol = new int [numRow][numCol];
        int [] rowFlags = new int[numRow];
        int [] colFlags = new int[numCol];

        for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
            String cmd = sc.next();
            switch (cmd) {
                case "SIT": {
                    int r1 = sc.nextInt();
                    int c1 = sc.nextInt();
                    if (rowByCol[r1]==null) {
                        rowByCol[r1] = new int[numCol];
                    }
                    rowByCol[r1][c1] = 1;
                    rowFlags[r1] = 1;
                    colFlags[c1] = 1;
                }
                case "BOX": {
                    int r1 = sc.nextInt();
                    int c1 = sc.nextInt();
                    if (rowByCol[r1]==null || rowByCol[r1][c1]!=1) {
                        System.out.println("N");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Y");
                    }
                }
                case "ROW": {
                    int r1 = sc.nextInt();
                    if (rowFlags[r1]==1) {
                        System.out.println("Y");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("N");
                    }
                }
                case "COL": {
                    int c1 = sc.nextInt();
                    if (colFlags[c1]==1) {
                        System.out.println("Y");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("N");
                    }
                } 
                default: {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grids newGrids = new Grids();
        newGrids.run();
    }
}
```

**Input**

```
11 2 2
SIT 0 1
BOX 0 1
BOX 0 0
BOX 1 1
ROW 0
ROW 1
COL 0
COL 1
SIT 1 1
ROW 1
COL 1
```

This is the simple program I tried replicating the bug with[Code and 2 set of inputs in comments]

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        String str1 = sc.next();
        String str2 = sc.next();
    }
}

//2 xyz abc

/*
2
xyz
abc
*/
```

Comment: Did you try calling `sc.nextLine()` after the switch ends? Likely scanner has to consume the newline character before going to the next line.

Comment: That was a possibility I thought of, haven't tried it yet. I haven't had problems with the scanner until this particular data set. Could it be because of the trailing spaces that follows after each line?

Comment: Most professional Java developers use Two scanners, one for strings, the other for numbers. This is because it is easy to end up in a situation, where you forget to consume a hidden `\n` in the scanner.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth Yes, absolutely. But even without the trailing space, I think it still has to consume `\n` somehow, so the `nextLine()` is needed.

Comment: You need to go to the next line before the loop for with sc.nextLine();

Comment: @Dylan Are you sure? I'd rather think that most professional java developers know how Scanner works and write the proper code to deal with it. Using two scanners to wrap the same stream is just confusing and I consider it a bad practice. And in fact I never met a professional developer who used multiple scanners on the same stream. Can you elaborate? Do you have any source on that?

Comment: Hi guys, why doesn't this problem occur on the simple program I tried replicating the problem on. I'm still not convinced by the problem here

Comment: You don't need to consume extra newline. That's not how `next` and `nextInt` work. You are missing the `break`'s after your switch cases, so it just continues after `SIT` and calls `nextInt` again when you type `BOX` which throws an input mismatch exception

Comment: @GBlodgett wow that's a great answer, somehow adding it works. Strange enough, the error started at the first `int` after `"SIT"`, before the future position of `break`. The rationale for the occurrence of the bug still amazes me.

Comment: I should probably clarify my above comment. You don't need to consume newline when calling `next` or `nextInt` after `next/nextInt`. If you are mixing them with calls to `nextLine()`, *then* you will need to consume the newline, which is where the common `Scanner is skipping nextLine after nextFoo` comes from

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth When I ran this code in the first call to `nextInt` in `BOX` after it fell through the cases without a `break`

Comment: @GBlodgett Hmm so your error is seen only in the first call to `nextInt` in `BOX` while I have seen it in `SIT`. This is rather interesting